# How to create top 10 words from a text after removing stopwords in Python

Tags: python-3.x

This is my code. How can I modify it to remove stopwords? I am new at this. I am unsure of where to start at. Thanks.

```
    #Top 10 words (stopwords included) for pinocchio.txt
    # Start by splitting the file into lowercase words.
    words2 = open('HW3-Pinocchio.txt', encoding ="utf8").read().lower().split()

    # Get the set of unique words.
    print("\nFor pinocchio.txt:")
    uniques2 = []
    for word in words2:
      if word not in uniques2:
        uniques1.append(word)

    # Make a list of (count, unique) tuples.
    counts1 = []
    for unique in uniques2:
      count2 = 0              # Initialize the count to zero.
      for word in words2:     # Iterate over the words.
        if word == unique:   # Is this word equal to the current unique?
          count2 += 1         # If so, increment the count
      counts2.append((count2, unique))

    counts2.sort()            # Sorting the list puts the lowest counts first.
    counts2.reverse()         # Reverse it, putting the highest counts first.
    # Print the ten words with the highest counts.
    for i in range(min(10, len(counts2))):
      count, word = counts2[i]
      print('%s %d' % (word, count))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out nltk.corpus.stopwords.words from the natural language toolkit. This will give you a list of stop words for a given language.

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

words2 = open('HW3-Pinocchio.txt', encoding ="utf8").read().lower().split()
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

print("\nFor pinocchio.txt:")
uniques2 = []
for word in words2:
    if word not in stop_words and word not in uniques2:
        uniques2.append(word)
```

In the original it seems like your `uniques1` variable should be `uniques2`. Besides that the above snippet is the same as your code with an extra check for membership to the `stop_words` set before addition to `uniques2`. The rest of your code should work.

Also consider using a set instead of a list for `uniques2`:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

words2 = open('HW3-Pinocchio.txt', encoding ="utf8").read().lower().split()
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

print("\nFor pinocchio.txt:")
uniques2 = set()
for word in words2:
    if word not in stop_words and word not in uniques2:
        uniques2.add(word)
```

Comment: Can you show me more in code? I am trying to follow you. Thanks.